# Selecting ordered and unique values from one to many mysql relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many, phpbb

In [phpbb3](/questions/tagged/phpbb3) I want to select latest 10 active topics. i.e topics that lastly has posts. In the PHPbb3 schema, the table `topics` has many `posts`. In order to achieve this, I tried the following SQL

```
    SELECT DISTINCT (`t_topics`.`topic_id`), `t_topics`.topic_title   FROM 
`t_topics` , `t_posts` WHERE `t_posts`.topic_id = `t_topics`.topic_id
 ORDER BY `t_posts`.post_id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

However, there is a topic that I'm sure that it has the latest post and it comes at the end of records.

I tried to remove `DISTINCT` However, I got have the correct order, but there are repeated topics. I want to get the correct order with no repeated topics but I don't know how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by clause instead of Distinct on `t_topics`.`topic_id`.
Query is : SELECT `t_topics`.`topic_id`, `t_topics`.topic_title FROM `t_topics` , `t_posts` WHERE `t_posts`.topic_id = `t_topics`.topic_id GROUP BY `t_topics`.`topic_id`  ORDER BY `t_posts`.post_id DESC LIMIT 10;

Comment: The problem is that the topic of most latest post, is returned as latest one in the results!